# Custom Toast not working on ICS

Tags: android, android-layout

I have series of `Toast` messages in a module which displays a `Toast` each time the user presses a button. To reduce the queuing time I am just passing the value to the method so that it does not end up till it finish the scheduled duration.

Like this:

```
dt("on button press");


private void dt(final String message) {

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.totext);

    toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    toast.cancel();
    text.setText(message);
    text.setTextSize(16);

    toast.show();

}
```

My problem is this code works perfectly on Gingerbread and lower versions of Android.
But it does not work on ICS and Jelly Bean?

What's the problem?

Comment: Maybe related to the `cancel()` before the `show()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is with the [`Toast.cancel()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#cancel%28%29) you're calling. I believe, before Honeycomb, `cancel()` *only* hid it if it was already showing. However, in later implementations, it has the following behavior (emphasis is mine):

> Close the view if it's showing, or **don't show it if it isn't showing yet**.

You'll want to move the call to `cancel()` to before the `new Toast()` (and of course, check if it's `null` first):

```
private void dt(final String message) {

    TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.totext);

    if (toast != null) {
        toast.cancel(); // Move me here!
    }
    toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());

    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 0);
    toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.setView(layout);
    text.setText(message);
    text.setTextSize(16);

    toast.show();

}
```

Comment: Thanks Eric, it worked , but i am still confused how the previous code work on Ginger Bread?

Comment: @NewMotive As I said, I think that on Gingerbread and lower, the behavior was limited to *only* "Close the view if it's showing"; that is, in old implementations, `cancel()` had no effect before `show()` was called.

Comment: @Eric I ran your code but there is no toast. pls help me here

Comment: @kAnNaN You should start a new question with your exact problem and the code you are using. The comments section was not meant for solving new issues.